# Sass, Compass, compile all CSS file to one

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Now, while I am developing my project I have three files, "main.css", "about.css" and "news.css" (for example). Is it possible to compile them into one "final.css" for production?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The SASS [import directive](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) is used to import the contents of one file into another, so you could create a file `final.scss` whose contents are:

```
@import 'main';
@import 'about';
@import 'news';
```

You'd then need to rename your files to have "scss" extensions so the import directive will find them. If you don't want the `main.scss`, `about.scss`, and `news.scss` files to compile to CSS files themselves, you can use [partials](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials) by prefixing the filenames with an underscore (i.e., `_main.scss`, `_about.scss`, `_news.scss`).

Comment: Is it the preferred way to compile all scss in one css file?

Comment: Yes, usually. Combining all CSS into a single file helps with performance by reducing the number of HTTP requests per page. Here's a good reference: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#num_http