# compass makes extra font-awesome folder during watch

Tags: sass, font-awesome, compass

So I'm going mad because I can't figure this out. I succesfully installed twitter bootstrap in sass and made it work with compass. I also decided I'm going to use font-awesome and struggled a bit but made it work. However I want everything imported into one styles.css and even though it works, in the process I have subdirectory with font-awesome.css that just has the same extra code and takes up the space.

I figured this must be some sort of compass and ruby in the works, any changes I try to make with *.rb files end up with compass crashing so I don't know where to start.
So the question basically is: how do I stop compass from creating extra folders and just compile *.scss files into 1 *.css file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass, Compass, compile all CSS file to one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025865/sass-compass-compile-all-css-file-to-one)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the SASS Font Awesome files are setup to process into it's own CSS file.

When using `@import`, make sure your targeted file is prefixed with an underscore else that will be both imported AND processed alone.

For example:

`font-awesome.scss` imported via `@import "font-awesome";` will imported AND be processed alone too.

`_font-awesome.scss` imported via `@import "font-awesome";` will only be imported.